# How to create Matlab dictionaries that use arrays as keys

Tags: matlab, dictionary

To simply translate directions given as a 1x2 double array into strings, I want to use the new dictionary function. However giving arrays as a key results in an unexpected behavior of the dictionary.

To translate orientations into strings I tried to use the new dictionary function in MATLAB like the following example.

```
orientation_dict = dictionary([1, 0],"south", [-1, 0],"north", [0, 1],"east", [0, -1],"west");
```

However this results in

```
orientation_dict = 

  dictionary (double ⟼ string) with 3 entries:

    1  ⟼ "east"
    0  ⟼ "west"
    -1 ⟼ "west"
```

The dictionary I want would look like this

```
orientation_dict = 

  dictionary (1x2 double ⟼ string) with 4 entries:

    [1, 0]  ⟼ "south"
    [-1, 0]  ⟼ "north"
    [0, 1]  ⟼ "east"
    [0, -1] ⟼ "west"
```

Is using arrays as keys even possible in the current MATLAB 2023a version?

Comment: Apparently that's not possible. According to the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dictionary.html), with the syntax `d = dictionary(keys,values)` _Individual elements of `keys` must be scalars of the same data type or of compatible data types_. With the syntax `d = dictionary(k1,v1,...,kN,vN)` (which you are using) it does not say, but I tested on R2023a and it seems to only use the first entry of each array as key, as in your example

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use scalar `cell` instances as the key:

```
>> orientation_dict = dictionary({[1, 0]},"south", {[-1, 0]}, ...
    "north", {[0, 1]},"east", {[0, -1]},"west")

orientation_dict = 

  dictionary (cell ⟼ string) with 4 entries:

    {[1 0]}  ⟼ "south"
    {[-1 0]} ⟼ "north"
    {[0 1]}  ⟼ "east"
    {[0 -1]} ⟼ "west"
```

(The same approach is required if you want to store non-scalar values too)